# Command Prompt Unable to access jarfile error

Tags: java, jar, command-prompt

so my program takes two text files, InputFile.txt and OutputFile.txt, and copies the data from InputFile to OutputFile. It works perfectly fine when in Eclipse, but I need to be able to run it from Command Prompt. However, when I use the line:

```
java -jar Copy.jar InputFile.txt OutputFile.txt
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Unable to access jarfile Copy.jar
```

I have tried moving the entire folder from the eclipse workspace as some of the other questions claimed that worked, but it won't for me. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that you're running the command from the directory that the jar is in?

Comment: @Igor Yes, and I just found my mistake, I had an error in creating the jar file before I even got to the command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I found my own error. I made a mistake in creating a jar file, before I got to the command prompt. Make sure you have created a .jar file before trying to run one.